# Asking Suggestions regarding mysql optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysqltuner

Im running a dedicated server with around 20-25 sites, almost all of them running wordpress installations.
Running it over a cpanel setup.
For a while its mostly mysql eating most of the cpu and hitting high load times

```
mysql   0     61.69(cpu)  6.92(ram) /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

**Server config is**

```
Uptime             70 days 
Operating System   CentOS Linux 7 (Core) x64 File
Handles            14560 of 6511967 
Processes          342  
CPU Model          AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
Ram                64GB
```

I am trying to improve this and came across mysql tuner, here is what it has to say after running mysql with performance schema on for 2 days or more.
This isnt exactly my forte so the mycnf is just a blend of what I tried with an older mysqltuner suggestion but ive heard that the application would still require a human touch.

Would appreciate some help in optimizing the settings.

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.19 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.3.27-MariaDB-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err exists
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err(4M)
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err contains 31430 warning(s).
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err contains 23132 error(s).
[--] 60 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err
[--] 1) 2020-12-07  7:35:16 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2020-12-01 14:35:35 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2020-11-30 16:10:14 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2020-11-30 16:07:53 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2020-11-01  1:57:12 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2020-10-10 19:28:45 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 2020-10-10 19:28:32 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 2020-09-30  3:36:14 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 9) 2020-09-28 17:58:16 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 10) 2020-09-25 18:38:33 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 51 shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err
[--] 1) 2020-12-07  7:35:07 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2020-12-01 14:35:27 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2020-11-30 16:09:53 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 2020-11-30 16:07:33 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 2020-11-01  1:57:09 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 2020-10-10 19:28:39 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 2020-10-10 19:28:26 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 8) 2020-09-30  3:34:34 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 9) 2020-09-28 17:56:38 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 10) 2020-09-25 18:36:55 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 2.1G (Tables: 1387)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 3.2G (Tables: 2207)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 586.4K (Tables: 3)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 2d 5h 57m 24s (167M q [862.613 qps], 2M conn, TX: 21024G, RX: 379G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 62.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 43.5G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 5.0G global + 260.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 104M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 26.5G (42.17% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 43.5G (69.35% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (324K/167M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 55% (84/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (55/2878495)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 40.4% (102M cached / 254M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 3479297
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (11K temp sorts / 6M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 12813
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 66% (2M on disk / 3M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (40K created / 2M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 95% (4K open / 4K opened)
[OK] table_definition_cache(2097152) is upper than number of tables(3862)
[OK] Open file limit used: 7% (2K/40K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (13M immediate / 13M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 104.0M
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 12 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.3.27-MariaDB-log)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 24.9% (182M used / 734M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 700.0M/460.2M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (1B cached / 41K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 69.5% (804K cached / 558K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 4.0G/3.2G
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (0.78125 %): 16.0M * 2/4.0G should be equal to 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 32 for 8 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (102924116296 hits/ 102924220151 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 73.75% (4679039 hits/ 6344450 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1665411 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 99.1% (277M cached / 2M reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: OFF
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: OFF
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err file
    Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/server.name.here.err file
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Increasing the query_cache size over 128M may reduce performance
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit.ly/2TcGgtU
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_size (> 128M) [see warning above]
    join_buffer_size (> 2.0M, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    tmp_table_size (> 32M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 32M)
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=512M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=4)
```

**And here is what my.cnf currently has**
**Note:** This is now edited based on suggestions by Wilson and Rick, Will save and restart mysql and get back to you guys with updates.

```
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

[mysqld]
# Logging and performance measurement here
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/ryzen.dogestream.com.err
# for enhanced slow query log
log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain
performance-schema=1


max_allowed_packet=268435456
max_heap_table=32M
tmp_table_size=32M
open_files_limit=40000


# Buffer sizes 
join_buffer_size=2M
key_buffer_size=700M
sort_buffer_size=2M


# InnoDB stuff goes here
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=15G
innodb_log_file_size=16M
local-infile=0
# from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100
# should always match table_open_cache
innodb_open_files=9000


# Query stuff goes here
# from 128M to conserve RAM for more useful purposes
query_cache_size=0
# from 1 for OFF to avoid 3 million+ query cache prunes per day
query_cache_type=0
# from 2M to conserve RAM
query_cache_limit=0
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=mysql-slow.log
long_query_time=0.1


# It says cache it is here
table_definition_cache=-1
# from 3000 to reduce tables opened_tables count
table_open_cache=9000
# from 16 to accomodate your 84 concurrent users
thread_cache_size=256
```

Comment: What do you want to optimize _for_? What is the goal?

Comment: Lesser cpu usage if possible, most of the time it hits high cpu usage even when the traffic isnt high. There is also the chance im doing some settings wrong or losing efficency with wrong values, would like to know if there are any such ones.

Comment: Why do you think lesser CPU usage is a good thing? Would you rather your hardware investments were underutilised?

Comment: By all means id prefer to make more good use of ram and cpu, its just that the system goes to100% usage many times a day with mysql always taking the larger portion, I am not able to identy the fault, figured its likely my poorly tuned sql config as the traffic on the server doesnt justify the excessive cpu usage

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
query_cache_size=0  # from 128M to conserve RAM for more useful purposes
query_cache_type=0  # from 1 for OFF to avoid 3 million+ query cache prunes per day
query_cache_limit=0  # from 2M to conserve RAM
```

REMOVE from your my.cnf

```
max_heap_table=32M   not a valid configuration item
table_cache = 6K  not a valid configuration item
thread_cache = 256  not a valid configuration item
```

Changes to your values,

```
table_open_cache=9000  # from 3000 to reduce tables opened_tables count
```

add innodb_open_files=9000  # should always match table_open_cache

```
thread_cache_size=256  # from 16 to accomodate your 84 concurrent users
log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain  # for enhanced slow query log
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
```

Expect these changes to reduce CPU busy.  View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance improvements.

Comment: About thread_cache=256  # from 16 to accomodate your 84 concurrent users, so if my users are say.. 800 at times, should I adjust the value to 1024? should i not keep it higher either way?

Comment: @SawadaTsunayoshi Please notice the Answer has been edited.  thread_cache should be removed, it is not a valid configuration item.  Thread_cache_size at 256 would be good until you have monitored SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'threads_created'; after 24 hours to decide on increasing thread_cache_size tp cover your workload of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections';

Comment: Edited server cnf/Edited question and restarted mysql. Im noticing connects roam around 200-300 atm

Comment: Is your system performance improved from your perspective?

Comment: It is, assuming traffic has not increased/decreased the daily resource usage alerts have reduced to maybe 1-3 per day instead of 10 per day. So yeah, there is an improvement.  Im hoping that after we disable performance schema things might improve slightly further

Comment: I would encourage you to download our Utility Script findfragtables.sql to allow monitoring your fragmented tables and OPTIMIZE the tables that have more than 10% FREE SPACE used to improve table performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tune away CPU problems (usually).

Change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 15G.

You are using a mixture of engines (InnoDB/MyISAM).  You should move toward using only InnoDB.  When changing, decrease key_buffer_size and increase innodb_buffer_pool_size.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

You can improve the indexes in `postmeta`; this will cut back on CPU.  Also on I/O, if necessary.

details: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

You already have the slowlog turned on.  Use `pt-query-digest` to summarize it.  Then present the first few queries.  (I expect you will find `postmeta` is involved in most of the slow queries.)

The numbers say you are the fence between the Query Cache helping versus hurting.  If you do turn it off, carefully measure performance before and after the change -- to see if the change helped or hurt.

Comment: Working on the sites to shift em all to InnoDB, nearly all tables are innodb except for a few in a website. Will look into the postmeta thing.